# How to avoid cast using QToolBox?

Tags: c++, qt

I know that cast should be avoided and I´m trying to do it, but I can´t see how to do it using a QToolBox.

The window I´m building has a QToolBox for the user chose which operation he wants to do and inside the toolbox are the specific parameters to each operation. The apply button is outside the QToolBox.

When the user clicks the apply button I have to get which operation he has chosen and its parameters.

The problem is that QToolBox currentWidget() method returns a QWidget that is a class that I can´t change. So I can´t use virtual methods or something like that. The only way I see to get the parameters is using cast.

Here is some code to show my problem:

```
class BaseOperation : QWidget {
    public:
    virtual int getParameter() = 0;
}

class Operation1 : public BaseOperation {
...
}

class Operation2 : public BaseOperation {
...
}
...
_ui->toolBox->addItem(new Operation1(this), "OP 1");
_ui->toolBox->addItem(new Operation2(this), "OP 2");
...
QWidget* curItem = _ui->toolBox->currentWidget();

BaseOperation* op = dynamic_cast<BaseOperation*>(op);

op.getParameter();
```

Is there a better way to do what I want? I thought of using the item index in the toolbox and a hash map to do it, but this does not seem very OOP.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you do. What's more: since you statically know that `curItem` is-a `BaseOperation`, that cast should be a `static_cast`.

Answer (score -1):

You can track [widget changes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbox.html#currentChanged), map index to concrete `Operation` class (not using hashmap, but simple switch-case) and then `static_cast<>` it, but that's what dynamic cast does for you, basically.

Using dynamic cast is perfectly OK in this case, IMO.

Answer (score -2):

A possible different approach that avoids casts entirely is  to use [`setProperty("name", QVariant(value))`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) to associate the data you need to the widgets, and then get the data back from the current widget using [`property("name").toInt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property) - this avoids casts and  defining separate classes if what you need is an integer value (or something else reasonably simple)

Comment: ... and then still *casting* the `QVariant` returned by `property`. What for, given `QToolBox`'s purpose is to give access to its contents?

Comment: ...you don't need a cast if the value that is needed is an int or something else simple...